# && operator returns 0 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like this.

```
  const items = [{ label : "foo" value : 1 },
                 { label : "bar" value : 2 },]
```

When I have `value1 = 1 value2 = 2 value3 = 0` , and execute this code.

```
[value1  && items.find(({value}) => value === value1).label,
 value2  && items.find(({value}) => value === value2).label,
 value3  && items.find(({value}) => value === value3).label,]
```

It returns result `["foo","bar",0]` and 0 shows up on screen.
What I want is empty string instead of 0 like this `["foo","bar",""]`
How I can do this?

Comment: Where do you expect the `""` to come from?

Comment: `value3  && items.find(({value}) => value === value3).label || ''`

Comment: @palaѕн, does not work, if not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a default value.

```
const
    items = [{ label: "foo" value: 1 }, { label: "bar" value: 2 }],
    result = [1, 2, 3].map(v =>
        v && state.items.find(({ value }) => value === v)?.label || '');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace

```
value3 && items.find(({value}) => value === value3).label
```

with

```
value3 && (items.find(({value}) => value === value3).label ? 'your value' : '')
```